# Is the field $\mathbb{F}_{64}$ the splitting field of $x^8-x$ over $\mathbb{F}_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Is the field $\mathbb{F}_{64}$ the splitting field of $x^8-x$ over $\mathbb{F}_4$? What I find is:

Let $E$ be the splitting field of $x^8-x$ over $\mathbb{F}_4.$ Thus, we have $E$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_8.$ Since $64=2^6, 8=2^3,$ $\mathbb{F}_{64}$ contains a subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_8.$ But how can I show that they are equal?

Comment: Why don't you consider the possibility that they are NOT equal?

Comment: How? I know it's a subfield, but how to show it's a proper subfield?

Comment: F_8 has 8 elements, F_64 has 64 elements. Obviously the inclusion is proper?

Comment: $ \mathbb{F}_8 $ doesn't contain $ \mathbb{F}_4 $, as the multiplicative group of $ \mathbb{F}_4 $ has an element of order 3, and the multiplicative group of $ \mathbb{F}_8 $ does not. More generally, any finite extension of $ \mathbb{F}_4 $ is isomorphic to a finite field of the form $ \mathbb{F}_{4^n} $ where $ n \geq 1 $ is an integer.

Comment: What Starfall said. Your mistake was in forgetting that the splitting field of any polynomial *over a field $K$* must contain $K$. Don't worry about it too much though. It becomes a second nature after a while :-)

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to check that $ \mathbb{F}_{64} $ is the smallest field containing $ \mathbb{F}_4 $ in which $ X^8 - X $ has $ 8 $ roots. First, note that any element of $ \mathbb{F}_{64} $ is a root of $ X^{64} - X = X(X^{63} - 1)$, and the latter factor is divisible by $ X^7 - 1 $ so that $ X^8 - X $ indeed splits in $ \mathbb{F}_{64} $. On the other hand, the only field extension of $ \mathbb{F}_4 $ smaller than $ \mathbb{F}_{64} $ is $ \mathbb{F}_{16} $, and $ \mathbb{F}_{16}^{\times} $ cannot have an element of order $ 7 $ by Lagrange, meaning that $ X^7 - 1 $ cannot split. Therefore, $ \mathbb{F}_{64} $ is the smallest such field, and is by definition the splitting field.

Comment: We don't have that definition to verify that the smallest field of a field is the splitting field.

Comment: The *definition* of the splitting field of a polynomial over some base field is the smallest field extension of the base field in which the polynomial splits. If you did not define it this way, I have no idea how you did it.

Comment: But you do believe that the field $\mathbb{F}_{64}$ is the splitting field of $x^8-x$ over $\mathbb{F}_4$, right?

Comment: I don't believe, I know.